# Laravel page expired 419 only sometimes

Tags: laravel, csrf, expired-sessions

I have a view in my Laravel application that has a form with the @csrf inside. The problem is that I faced the 419 Page expired exception only sometimes. 
When I refreshed the page, the login page appeared and after login, a few times the form submission was done successfully but again, 419 occurred. 
I saw the other topics. All of them told that the solution is adding the @CSRF directive to the form.
But in my special case, the @CSRF exists.
Help me please.

---

### Update

Here is a part of my source code. It's a simple html form with the @CSRF inside it.

```
<form method="POST" action="/settingUrl">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="myfield" />
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Well, if you open the login page, leave it for sometime (lets say for example 30min) and come back, the csrf-token would have already expired, which explains why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working with other pages. So, the session shouldn't be expired, I think. I'm routing around, going other pages, but only in my setting page, after some successful form submission, the page will be expired.

Comment: Do you mind if you share samples of your code?

Comment: The wired thing about this problem is that I just have a simple login form. It also consists the @CSRF directive. I updated the question with a small part of my form.